# How to Parse JSON object partially to Java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I am working on a big json output file which is coming as response but I want to parse only some of the fields in my logic.

For ex: The `JSON` looks like this

```
{
 "lastName":"Smith",
"address":{
    "streetAddress":"21 2nd Street",
     "city":"New York",
     "state":"NY",
     "postalCode":10021
},
 "age":25,
 "phoneNumbers":[
        {
        "type":"home", "number":"212 555-1234"
        },
     {
        "type":"fax", "number":"212 555-1234"
     }
 ],
 "firstName":"John"
}
```

I have created the necessary JAVA classes and mapping the `JSON` Object to Java object using `GSON`. Since, the above `JSON` is just a sample one in my case I have big one which is generating around 15 classes.

Currently i have to create following classes files:

```
- Employee.class
- Address.class
- PhoneNumber.class
```

I want to avoid creating PhoneNumber.class and its nested class using GSON.

Basically My query is like in above json I don't want `phoneNumbers` and its internal `objects` so how can i ignore those fields so that i have to construct less Java Class files and still it is mapped to Java `Object`.

So I want to avoid making classes for `PhoneNumbers` fields and the nested fields inside PhoneNumbers.

Comment: Then don't make a `PhoneNumber` class, and Gson will silently **ignore** the `phoneNumbers` json field. I don't see the problem. Did you even *try* just removing it from your class to what would happen? That would have been a lot faster for you, than writing this question and waiting on answers.

Comment: i think you can use HashMap if u don't want to create classes

Comment: '@IgnoreUnkown' and '@Ignore' annotations will do the job

Comment: @Andreas I have already tried this approach before but i was getting exception HttpMessageNotReadableException Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field phoneNumber

Comment: @Anirudh Yours suggestion was close which i was looking so after including @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) it was working

Comment: Glad I could help..!!

Comment: `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is `Jackson` annotation, not `Gson`! Please make sure which JSON library you're using, @Andreas's suggestion should work if you're using `Gson` indeed!

Comment: `HttpMessageNotReadableException Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field ...` is not a GSON exception or is it? Maybe you have missed tags spring, jackson and accidentally added tag gson? So where is the code for de-serializing?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, `Employee` and `Address` classes are all you need:

```java
public class Employee {
    private String firstName, lastName;
    private int age;
    private Address address;
}
```

```java
public class Address {
    private String streetAddress, city, state;
    private int postalCode;
}
```

`new Gson().fromJson(json, Employee.class);`, where `json` is the raw JSON string, should then do what you want. Without sharing your code, it is hard to tell why it doesn't work for you.